# Check continuity with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

We have the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 , & x\geq 1 \\ x-1 , & x<1\end{cases}$$ Is the function continuous at $x_0=1$ ?

To check that using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion we have the following :

Let $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily.

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(1)|=|f(x)-1|$$ Do we take cases if $x<1$ and if $x>1$ ?

I mean do we do the following ?

For $x<1$ : $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(1)|=|f(x)-1|=|x-1-1|=|x-2|$$
For $x>1$ : $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(1)|=|f(x)-1|=|x^2-1|=|x+1|\cdot |x-1|$$ For this one we cannot find an upper bound since $|x+1|$ is not bounded, right?

Comment: Why are you trying to find upper bounds? Upper bounds have nothing to do with it.  Intuitively you should know that as $x\to 1^-$ we have $f(x)\to 0$ but for $x\to 1^+$ we have $f(x)\to 1$ so it isn't continuous and as $f(x_0) = f(1)=1$ we have $x\to 1^+$ is the "good" side and $x\to 1^-$ is the bad side.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is discontinuous at $1$ if $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall \delta>0, \exists x_0\in \Bbb{R} $ with $|x_0-1|<\delta$ but $|f(x_0)-1|\ge \epsilon$

---

Let $\delta>0$ be given. Now by Archimedean property of Real numbers, we can choose $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$

Let $x_0=1-\frac{1}{n}$ , then $|x_0-1|=|1-\frac{1}{n}-1|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta$

But

$\begin{align}|f(x_0) -1|&=|1-\frac{1}{n}-1-1|\\&=1+\frac{1}{n}>1\end{align}$

Choose $\epsilon=1$ , then $\forall\delta>0, \exists x_0=1-\frac{1}{n}\in (1-\delta, 1+\delta) $ but $|f(x_0)-1|>\epsilon$

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

We want to determine if $f$ is continuous at $x_0=1$.

We note that for $x\ge 1$, $f(x)=x^2$.  So, as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right, the limit is $1$.  This is also the value $f(1)=1$.

And for $x<1$, $f(x)=x-1$.  So, as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, the limit is $0$.

So, $f$ is not continuous at $1$.

To show this using a $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, we need to find a value of $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$, there exists a number $x_\delta \in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$, such that $|f(x_\delta)-f(x_0)|\ge \varepsilon$.  This is the negation of continuity of $f(x)$ at $x_0$.

Since the limits of $f$ from the right of $1$ and left of $1$ differ by $1$, lets test with $\varepsilon=1/2$ (any number between $0$ and $1$ will suffice).

Then, for any given $\delta>0$, we can find a number $x_\delta\in [1-\delta,1+\delta]$ such that  $|f(x_\delta)-f(1)|=|f(x_\delta)-1|\ge \varepsilon = 1/2$.  In fact, any number $1-\delta<x_\delta<1$ suffices.  Then, we have $|f(x_\delta)-1|=|x_\delta-2|\ge 1/2$ for $1-\delta<x_\delta<1$ and conclude that $f$ is discontinuous at $1$.

Comment: How does the fact that the right and the left limit differ by $1$ and $\epsilon$ ? I haven't really understood why we test $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Well, the limit from the right is $1$.  The limit from the left is $0$.   The difference of $1$ and $0$ is $1$.  So any $0<\varepsilon<1$ will suffice.  I chose $1/2$ as a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: But how exactly is $\epsilon$ related with the difference of the limits? I haven't really understood that.

Comment: @MaryStar We need to find an $\varepsilon>0$ for which $|f(x_\delta)-f(x_0)|\ge \varepsilon$.  If $f(x_0)=1$, and $f(x_\delta)<0$ for $x_\delta<1$, then we see that the difference of $1$ needs to exceed some $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.